# How to find individual radio from radio group and set check property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have radio group

```
      <input class="form-check-input" id="hasHeader0" name="hasHeader" type="radio" value="Yes">
      <input class="form-check-input" id="hasHeader1" name="hasHeader" type="radio" value="No">
```

then i have a jquery instance of radio group

```
         var radioGroup =   $("input:radio[name ='hasHeader']")
```

how do i find a individual radio based on value and then set its Check property to true.

i tried

```
   radioGroup.find("[value='Yes']").prop('checked', true);
```

and also tried

```
   radioGroup.find("input[value='Yes']").prop('checked', true);
```

Note that i already have the instance of radio group. So i am not looking for answer

```
   $("input[name='hasHeader'][value='Yes']").prop('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: You need to use `filter()` not `find()`.  `radioGroup` is already the radio buttons.  You don't need to find nested elements.  You need to filter the already found results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method will search for child elements but in your case use [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter) method to filter from a collection.

```
radioGroup.filter("[value='Yes']").prop('checked', true);
```

```js
var radioGroup =   $("input:radio[name ='hasHeader']")
radioGroup.filter("[value='Yes']").prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 Yes<input class="form-check-input" id="hasHeader0" name="hasHeader" type="radio" value="Yes">
 No<input class="form-check-input" id="hasHeader1" name="hasHeader" type="radio" value="No">
```